# Apple sign in with Federated amplify does not fetch auth session identity id or sub id

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

```
 func federatedSignIn(applegeneratedid: String, forWhichAuthProvider: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool, AWSApiErrors?) -> Void) {
        guard let plugIn = try? Amplify.Auth.getPlugin(for: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin().key), let authPlugIn = plugIn as? AWSCognitoAuthPlugin, case .awsMobileClient(let client) = authPlugIn.getEscapeHatch() else { return }
        client.federatedSignIn(providerName: forWhichAuthProvider, token: applegeneratedid) { states, error in
            if let error = error {
                completionHandler(false, .failed(error: error.localizedDescription))
            } else if let unwrappedState = states {
                completionHandler(true, nil)
            }
        }
    }

func fetchCurrentAuthSession(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, AWSApiErrors?) -> Void) {
        _ = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let session):
                AuthUDManager.set(true, forKey: .isAuthSessionUpdated)
                Logger.log("Is user signed in - \(session.isSignedIn)")
                if session.isSignedIn {
                    do {
                        let session = try result.get()
//                        // Get user sub or identity id
                        if let identityProvider = session as? AuthCognitoIdentityProvider {
                            let usersub = try identityProvider.getUserSub().get()
                            let identityId = try identityProvider.getIdentityId().get()
                            AuthUDManager.set(usersub, forKey: .loggedInUserSubID)
                            AppAnalytics.manager.reporter.setUserId(userId: usersub)
                            Logger.log("User sub - \(usersub) and identity id \(identityId)")
                        }
                        // Get cognito user pool token
                        if let cognitoTokenProvider = session as? AuthCognitoTokensProvider {
                            let tokens = try cognitoTokenProvider.getCognitoTokens().get()
                            AuthUDManager.set(tokens.idToken, forKey: .loggedInUserIDToken)
                            Logger.log("idToken token - \(tokens.idToken) ")
                            Logger.log("access token - \(tokens.accessToken) ")
                            Logger.log("refresh token - \(tokens.refreshToken) ")
                        }
                        // Get aws credentials
                        if let awsCredentialsProvider = session as? AuthAWSCredentialsProvider {
                            let credentials = try awsCredentialsProvider.getAWSCredentials().get()
                            print("Access key - \(credentials.secretKey) ")
                        }
                        completionHandler(true, nil)
                    } catch {
                        Logger.log("Fetch auth session failed with error - \(error)")
                        if let authError = error as? AuthError {
                            completionHandler(false, AuthApiErrorHandler(error: authError).handleAuthErrors())
                        } else {
                            completionHandler(false, .failed(error: AuthLocalizable.somethingWentWrong.localized()))
                        }
                   }
                } else {
                    Logger.log("Not logged In")
                    AuthUDManager.removeObject(forKey: .loggedInUserIDToken)
                    completionHandler(false, .notAuthorized)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                Logger.log("Fetch session failed with error \(error)")
                AuthUDManager.removeObject(forKey: .loggedInUserIDToken)
                completionHandler(false, .failed(error: error.localizedDescription))
            }
        }
    }
```

Fetch auth session failed with error - AuthError: Unexpected error occurred with message: An unknown error occurred\nRecovery suggestion: This should not happen. There is a possibility that there is a bug if this error persists. Please take a look at https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/issues to see if there are any existing issues that match your scenario, and file an issue with the details of the bug if there isn't. Issue encountered at:\nfile: /Users/pareshprajapati/Documents/Projects/theramind-app-ios/Pods/Amplify/Amplify/Categories/Auth/Error/AuthError.swift\nfunction: recoverySuggestion\nline: 80\nCaused by:\nError Domain=com.amazonaws.service.cognitoidentity.AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper Code=0 "Obtaining an identity id in another thread failed or didn't complete within 5 seconds." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Obtaining an identity id in another thread failed or didn't complete within 5 seconds.

It gives above error on extracting user sub id or identity id

Using these amplify version
Installing AWSAuthCore 2.26.5 (was 2.25.0)
Installing AWSCognitoIdentityProvider 2.26.5 (was 2.25.0)
Installing AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF 2.26.5 (was 2.25.0)
Installing AWSCore 2.26.5 (was 2.25.0)
Installing AWSMobileClient 2.26.5 (was 2.25.0)
Installing AWSPluginsCore 1.16.1 (was 1.13.4)
Installing Alamofire 5.4.4 (was 5.4.3)
Installing Amplify 1.16.1 (was 1.13.4)
Installing AmplifyPlugins 1.16.1 (was 1.13.4)

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @axunic Yes, For Federated sign-in you need to configure your backend with the federated identity provider. There is a lot to configure.